# Change color of bsTooltip boxes in shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny, tooltip

Is it possible to style the aesthetics of a tooltip box with `bsTooltip` in shiny? I have scoured SO for answers, but with respect to tooltips, all of the adjustments on aesthetics appear to be for widths only (ie [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320525/style-individual-bstooltip-shinybs-elements)). Consider the MWE from the [shinyBS Githug Pages document](https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/docs/Tooltips_and_Popovers.html), including only the `bsTooltip` portion and some modified CSS:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
shinyApp(
    ui =
        fluidPage(

            sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                    tags$style(
                        HTML(
                            "
                        .tooltip {
                        width: 400px;
                        text-color:black;
                        background-color:red;
                        }
                        "

                        )),

                    sliderInput("bins",
                                "Number of bins:",
                                min = 1,
                                max = 50,
                                value = 30),
                    bsTooltip("bins", "The wait times will be broken into this many equally spaced bins",
                              "right")
                ),
                mainPanel(

                )
            )
        ),
    server =
        function(input, output, session) {

        }
)
```

This results in the following:

[image]

It seems as if the div holding the tooltip is changing, but I would like to style the tooltip itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `.tooltip` you are styling the container, try `.tooltip-inner`, e.g.

```r
tags$style(HTML("
                .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
                width: 400px;
                color: white;
                background-color: red;
                }
                "))
```

[image]

You can find more tips [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tooltip.asp).

Comment: Great! With this code, I get the same color for all tooltips. But, can you also tell us how to get different background colors for two/multiple tooltips? I want one to have red background, the other green.

Comment: Anyone interested in answer to my question above, refer to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67851936